# Copy full folder to another folder in android 10

Tags: android, file, android-10.0, android-external-storage

I have an app in android 10 in which I am saving the images in the path below.

```
File f = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "myImages");
```

This path save the images in myImages folder but as everyone know with android 10 this folder will be created in Android/data/app.packagename/files/myImages so when I uninstall the app then the images folder also gets deleted.
What I did to solve this is that now I am using the code below to save images in the Pictures folder.

```
  final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "myImages";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        final ContentValues  contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);

        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

        OutputStream stream = null;
        Uri uri = null;

        try
        {
            final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);

            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
            }

            stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);

            if (stream == null)
            {
                throw new IOException("Failed to get output stream.");
            }

            if (inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream) == false)
            {
                throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            if (uri != null)
            {
                // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
                resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
        return uri;
```

This works well and all the images now save to Pictures folder but the problem is in my first app update there is different path and in the second update it has the path of the new picture. So I am trying to move files from the old path to new path in this app update so that if there are any images in old path then they can be copied to a new path and the app will work well.

**I use this code for copying data.**

```
 String fromdirectory = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+"/tempBooks/";
        File from = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+"/tempBooks/");
        final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "tempBooks";
 try{
      FileUtils.copyFile(fromdirectory, relativeLocation);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

**But it gives an exception that**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.package.name/files/myImages: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

**Please help me with this, I tried with few other methods too but this exception remains

Comment: `the problem is in my first app update there is different path and in the second update it has the path of the new picture. So I am trying to move files from the old path to new path ` Pretty unclear. Which paths? And why not directly copy to MediaStore Pictures directory?

Comment: `But it gives an exception that` What follows is a path to your directory. Not to one of your files. You did not tell which code causes it.

Comment: In the first line I have clearly written that I have used this path for saving images. Then later on I gave another code in which I used another path to save images. 
The exception code is also given in the end of the code. Please check again sir

Comment: did you find any solution.. @Aarks